# Monitoring app?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am currently designing an Android application which monitor  the users activity I need to access the camera the thing is in order to use the camera the application needs to request permission from the user but I am designing a monitor application the user does not no that the application is running so is there any way to bypass the user request permission and gain the permission

Comment: You only need to request camera permission once - unless the user subsequently revokes the permission then it will persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to bypass the user request permission and gain the permission ?

You cannot, for security reason.

On API 22 and lesser, permissions are granted on app installation.

Moreover, on API 23 and higher you **have to** check and ask for permission when your app is launched  for all *dangerous* level permission (like [CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAMERA) permission). See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to request permissions.